# Show that $0$ is a regular value of $F$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, submanifold

> How can i show that $0$ is a regular value of $F:\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
> $$F(x,y,z)=(x^3+y^3+z^3-1,z-xy)$$
> I compute the diferential of $F$ obtaining:
> $$dF=\pmatrix{ 3x^2 & -y\cr 3y^2 & -x\cr 3z^2 &1}$$
> and i know that if $det[(dF)(dF)^t] \neq 0$ then $F$ is a submersion but compute this determinant and see the points where it is $0$ its hard.

Any hint or alternatively way to show that i will be very grateful.

Comment: First, you have to identify the set of $(x,y,z)$ such that $F(x,y,z) =0$. Then, you have to determine, for each value $(x,y,z)$ in this set, if $dF_{(x,y,z)}\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2$ is surjective. For example, bu computing the rank of the matrix you have determined in your question

Comment: Just so you know: The matrix of $dF$ needs to be transposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, you have to play with the equations $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 1$ and $z=xy$.

Let $Z = F^{-1}(0)$.
Let $(x,y,z)\in Z$, and consider the matrix of $dF_{(x,y,z)}$ in the canonical basis, which is
$$
\mathrm{Mat}_{\mathrm{can}}(dF_{(x,y,z)}) = \begin{pmatrix}3x^2 & 3y^2 & 3z^2 \\ -y & -x & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3x^2 & 3y^2 & 3x^2y^2 \\ -y & -x & 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
since on $Z$, $z=xy$.
(Note that this is the transpose of what you have stated: indeed, $dF_{(x,y,z)}$ goes from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$, not the converse.)

Let us show that this matrix has rank $2$.
First of all, $x$ and $y$ cannot be simultaneously vanishing: By contradiction, if $x=y=0$, then $x^3+y^3+z^3-1=0$ gives $z=1$, while $z-xy=0$ gives $z=0$.

Without loss of generality, let us assume that $x\neq 0$.
Consider the determinant of the matrix formed by the first and last columns:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}3x^2 & 3x^2y^2 \\ -y & 1\end{vmatrix} = 3x^2 + 3x^2y^3 = 3x^2(1+y^3).
$$
It vanishes if and only if $y^3=-1$, that is if and only if $y=-1$.
Assume by contradiction that $y=-1$.
Then $z-xy=0$ leads to $z=-x$. Hence, $x^3+y^3+z^3-1=0$ leads to $-2=0$, which is obviously false.
If follows that $y\neq -1$ and that $dF_{(x,y,z)}$ has rank $2$.
Hence, $(x,y,z)$ is a regular point of $F$.

This being true for all $(x,y,z)$ in $Z$, $0$ is a regular value for $F$.